# Is it possible to determine the progress of an rm command?

Tags: rm

Using `rm -rf LargeDirectory` to delete a large directory can take a large amount of time to complete depending on the size of the directory.

Is it possible to get a status update or somehow monitor the progress of this deletion to give a rough estimate as to where along in the process the command is?

Comment: Try `watch -n 5 du -s LargeDirectory`.  Watch as it goes to zero.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: on MacOS, have to install it with `brew install watch`, or see [here](http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/22/install-watch-command-on-os-x/) for instructions.

Answer (score 39):

from

```
man rm
```

use the -v option:

```
-v, --verbose
explain what is being done
```

Comment: that’s not progress though. how does “now deleting foo/bar” help you determine how far the complete thing is?

Comment: @flyingsheep believe it removes everything in alphabetical order, at least in OSX it does, so it does help in some way..

Answer (score 31):

I see the question is old. I want to share what it works for me to maybe help some else.

I get the progress bar using `pv` command line [Pipe Viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml)

This is the command

```
rm -rv DIR_OR_FILE_NAME | pv -l -s $( du -a DIR_OR_FILE_NAME | wc -l ) > /dev/null
```

If you need root permissions for the dir or file to delete,

```
sudo rm -rv DIR_OR_FILE_NAME | pv -l -s $( sudo du -a DIR_OR_FILE_NAME | wc -l ) > /dev/null
```

- `rm -rv`: `-r` to recursively remove DIRs and files. `-v` verbose it lists all the files and directories that is removing.
- `pv -l -s`: `-l` to count lines instead of bytes. `-s` set the total lines to be removed.
- `$( du -a <dir_or_file> | wc -l )`: `du -a` returns a list all files and directories from the dir specified. `wc -l` returns the count of lines outputted by `du -a`.
- `> /dev/null`: send the output of `rm -rv` to nowhere.

Comment: Good idea.  This may give an incorrect file/directory count if any names contain newlines; ``find {dir} -printf . | wc -c`` would be safer (but `-printf` is a GNU extension).

Comment: This actually is what I was looking for, thank you. Other comments left something lacking.

Comment: `du` will fail on items that were already deleted too quickly.  Those errors can probably just be silenced, maybe by filtering stderr or wherever they are sent.  Otherwise a great solution for long deletions.

Comment: This is AMAZING! It would have helped a few years ago if I'd have known about it - I was moving large chunks of data around and had no idea how long each move would take.

Answer (score 7):

You can view the progress of any currently running commands with Coreutils Progress Viewer(`cv`). It isn't like issuing a single command, but you can see the progress with it.

[image: example of CV being used]

I'm sure someone can come up with an alias to run this with the command.
It also works with `cp, mv, dd, tar, gzip/gunzip, cat, etc.`.
More details about it can be found at

[gitthub Xfennec/progress](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress)

Comment: Since progress (as "cv" is now known) tracks open files and rm does not open the files it deletes, this may not actually be very useful.

Comment: @dhag Your right, I thought that this would work for rm. Now I'm debating whether to remove the answer. hmm

Comment: @Ashitakalax It's a bit off-topic, but how to get this prompt that you're using? Looks really cool.

Comment: @zupazt3 it looks like Oh My Zsh (https://ohmyz.sh/)

Answer (score 4):

If the directory to be removed has a very large number of files, `du` command might take a long time to compute the size of remaining files.

If you have a general sense of how much space the files take up or how much free space there should be after deleting the files, then as an alternative, while the `rm` command is running, in a separate terminal session/window, try **watching how much free-space is left/used on the HDD**.

For example:

Run `watch df -h` (all devices) or `watch df -h /dev/path/to/disk` (specific HDD)

Comment: This was perfect for my purposes, monitoring the progress of deleting an old time machine backup on a NAS to free up space, where the directory was big enough that even running `ls` would hang for a while.

Answer (score 3):

```
rm * & watch 'ls -1 | wc -l'
```

It removes all files and watch remaining number of files (in current directory)

```
rm * & watch 'du -h'
```

it removes all files and watch remaining directory size (in current
directory)

You can customize 'rm' command, e.g. 'rm -rf *', removing without confirmation all files/directories recursively (in current directory)

Comment: `rm` doesn't write to _stdout_, and `watch` doesn't read from _stdin_, so the pipe between them is pointless. If you want to run them at the same time try `rm -f * & watch 'ls | wc -l'` or consider `rm -v *`

Comment: hmm, okay. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Cross-posting from https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/991, if you have `tqdm` installed (`snap install tqdm`, `conda install tqdm`, `pip3 install tqdm`, etc) then

```
rm -rfv LargeDirectory | tqdm --total $(du -a LargeDirectory | wc -l) >/dev/null
```